# ERROR after installing certificate - Linux - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, linux, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have been re-searching this issue for the below and I have seen many people with the same issue. Upon my resolution, I was able to verify that I had an old certificate and was able to install the new certificate. Upon installing the new certificate in cacerts, I still receive the below when trying to download the file from the url.

```
   cannot download the xml file
   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: u
   nable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

The commands that I used is below:

```
   /app/financial/prd/thirdparty/java/bin/keytool -import -alias fincert1 -file /tmp/treasurydirect5.cer -keystore 
   /app/financial/prd/thirdparty/java/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

As a last resort, I decided to ask the question on here because it has been asked multiple times with a resolution from the above. However, I'm still receiving the error after installing the new certificate.

I was able to confirm that the new certificate was installed by running the below:

```
  /app/financial/prd/thirdparty/java/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore  /app/financial/prd/thirdparty/java/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass <password>
```

Any additional details would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Ensure you are using the correct JVM. Try to debug the ssl connection to see the certificate presented by server and the content of your truststore

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at this and revert back. How would this be an issue with a new certificate update? It seems the new certificate update but in order to correctly download the file, I would need to update the JVM with the correct version